# Don't let late answers bump an _answered_ question until approval

Tags: feature-request, review, stack-exchange, bump, late-answers

I don't know what percentage of late answers are actually worth bumping an old but answered question at all, but I'm pretty sure if said late answer *is*, then the bumping could at least wait until the answer is no longer in the late answer queue.

**edit** Note that I'm not suggesting this for SO alone, but for SE in general - especially for sites where there are many new questions each day but no "interesting" tab.

Comment: (If you think this should even apply to unanswered questions, upvote this comment)

Comment: Bumping a question that got a new answer means that the answer is seen by more people and will be voted on. That's A Good Thing™.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes and no - it also means removing another question prematurely from front page without deserving it; the old answer already had its upvote-window. **edit** Or do you mean prominence for the _new_ answer? That's why I suggest after the answer is no longer in the late-answer queue, because then it deserves the attention

Comment: How about creating a second filter moderation on late-answers, to incentive good late-answers, and late-answers on questions  with no accepted **and** upvoted answers. This might decrease with time, questions being bumped up, for example, with "not an answer" late-answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182643/second-filter-moderation-on-late-answers-minimum-reputation-and-tag-badge-requi

Comment: @AndreSilva Nice idea, +1!

Answer (score 6):

I disagree; I *like* this behavior.

Fundamentally, I think that new answers bumping up a question is actually a good thing because it gets more eyes on those new answers. That serves several purposes: as needed, the answers can be voted on, improved by edits, flagged, or removed.

If they *didn't* bump up the question, the new answers would most likely just get lost and miss out on being screened by the community.

I suppose that the argument is the "late answer" queue solves this problem, but I confess that I don't spend all that much time looking in the "late answer" and other queues. That's not to say I don't review and improve a lot of posts—I do—I just find them other ways. Mainly by looking at the questions that appear on the home page, a list of questions automatically customized to my areas of interest and/or expertise. Areas where I'm most qualified and most willing to spend my time reading, assessing, and improving posts.

On a site as large as Stack Overflow, with as many questions posted every minute on a dazzling array of topics, I really don't think that bumps are a serious problem. New questions aren't guaranteed much (any?) real time in the limelight just due to the sheer volume of new questions, even if there's no bumping whatsoever going on. If people want to find unanswered questions to answer, there are plenty of ways of doing that.

Comment: While I agree that a new answer should be examined by as many eyes as possible, there are more than enough late answers that are anything but answers and it would really suffice to waste the late-answer reviewers' time "only" - I do browse that queue regularly and consider it a great way to get rid of unhelpful things. And I don't see why a question should be bumped if the new "answer" isn't actually an answer

Comment: Re 3rd paragraph: That may be true on SO, but on other SE sites like math.SE or ArQAde there is no "interesting" tab but it _is_ feasible to skim through all fronpage questions once in a while. And there, an inappropriately bumped old question _is_ a waste of time

Comment: I still don't think it's a waste. That gives people a chance to view and audit that answer. You might learn something, you might upvote it, you might edit and improve it, you might help to burninate it. Either way, those are good things to have happen. It's good to know someone uses the queue, I just don't have enough time in the day to read/answer the questions I'm interested in *and* review a whole bunch of unrelated ones. So I combine the two.